# Почему кнопки не отправляются вертикальным списком?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Создаю объект клавиатуры и отправляю её пользователю

```
def get_button(label, color, payload=""):
return {
    "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": json.dumps(payload),
        "label": label
    },
    "color": color
}

keyboard = {
"one_time": False,
"buttons": [
    [
        get_button(label="Кнопка 1", color="positive"),
        get_button(label="Кнопка 2", color="negative"),
        get_button(label="Кнопка 3", color="primary"),
        get_button(label="Кнопка 4", color="negative")
    ]
]}
keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboard = str(keyboard.decode('utf-8'))
id = "id получателя"
vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Открыто меню!", "keyboard": keyboard,
                        "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```

Всё отправляется нормально, приходит горизонтальное меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь отправить это же меню вертикально *(каждую кнопку на отдельной строке), изменив сам объект клавиатуры таким образом:

```
keyboard = {
"one_time": False,
"buttons": [
    [
        [get_button(label="Кнопка 1", color="positive")],
        [get_button(label="Кнопка 2", color="negative")],
        [get_button(label="Кнопка 3", color="primary")],
        [get_button(label="Кнопка 4", color="negative")]
    ]
]}
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [911] Keyboard format is invalid: button [0][3] has invalid action
```

Мне сказали, что в функции get_button() указан payload как json.dumps(payload),
чтобы отправить вертикальное меню достаточно изменить этот параметр на "{\"button\": \"1\"}"
Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
def get_button(label, color, payload):
return {
    "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": json.dumps(payload),
        "label": label
    },
    "color": color
}
keyboard = {
"one_time": False,
"buttons": [
    [
        get_button(label="Кнопка 1", color="positive", payload="{\"button\":\"1\"}"),
        get_button(label="Кнопка 2", color="negative", payload="{\"button\":\"1\"}"),
        get_button(label="Кнопка 3", color="primary", payload="{\"button\":\"1\"}"),
        get_button(label="Кнопка 4", color="negative", payload="{\"button\":\"1\"}")
    ]
]}
```

Но кнопки всё равно отправляются в одну строку. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Вы не перемещаете кнопки на строки, добавлять кнопки на новых строках - `add_line()`.